# ¿Cómo colocar texto a la derecha de una figura hecha con HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

Me gustaría saber como hacer esto en HTML

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahora tengo lo siguiente:

```html
<div style="border-radius:50%;height:50px;width:50px;background: #b4a8a7;"> NATURAL
```

Soy principiante

Comment: Hola, no es una buena practicar realizar formas con un div. Los div son contenedores. Tu puedes crear formas geometricas con css facilmente y colocarlo dentro de un <div>. Ahora lo mas importante es... qué intentas hacer con este código? Cuál es tu objetivo?

Comment: Cuentanos más sobre lo que buscar hacer para orientarte sobre una solucion practica.

Comment: Hola Arturo, es buena practica intentar dar un contexto sobre lo que quieres lograr, cual es tu objetivo y lo que has intentado hasta ahora para poder lograrlo y si estas atorado en algo especifico mencionarlo, por ejemplo, quiero alinear el texto de tal forma pero la propiedad tal no me funciona, o similar, esto ayuda a que las personas puedan comprender mejor tu problema y resolverlo más fácilmente, puedes leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @LilibethQ Muchas gracias por la información. Si, no estoy muy puesto en eso, pero el caso es que tengo una variable, que al hacerle un var_dump me despliega esa información, ese div, y no puedo modificar la variable o esa estructura del div. El div Dibuja el circulo gris y solo busco una forma de ponerle un texto a su lado como si una muestra de un color de uñas se tratase.

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta alinear con table, una fila y dos celdas:

```html
    <table>
    <td>
    <div style="border-radius:50%;height:50px;width:50px;background: #b4a8a7;"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
    NATURAL
    </td>
</table>
```